# reversing an array in loop in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a programme that reverses words on each line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char word[2001], letter;
    int size = 0, i;
    while((letter = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) 
    {
        word[size] = letter;
        size++;
    }

    for(i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this code works but it reverses everything I mean for example if I input

```
Hello
my
friends
```

the output is:

```
sdneirf
ym
olleH
```

But I want an output like this:

```
olleH
ym
sdneirf
```

what is the thing I have to fix?

Comment: Read the line into a buffer with `fgets`

Comment: I suppose you would have to look for word delimiters and then reverse the individual words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do printing at end of each lines.

Also return value of `fgetc()` should be stored to `int`, not `char`, because the return value is `int` and converting it to `char` may be obstacle when compareing with `EOF`.

fixed example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char word[2001];
    int size = 0, i;
    for (;;)
    {
        int letter = fgetc(stdin);
        if (letter == '\n' || letter == EOF) {
            for(i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                printf("%c", word[i]);
            }
            if (size > 0) putchar('\n');
            size = 0;
            if (letter == EOF) break;
        } else {
            word[size] = letter;
            size++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know about that kind of use of for loop: for(;;).